# Filter url from string and match the domain names

Tags: php, regex

i have to match and filter url from string and match the domain names.For example the string is

> $s="Does anyone have a working preg_match script for checking and
>   validating a correct url submission into a html form
>   http:/stackoverflow.com/questions/ask validating http:/google.com";

find the string contain any url and  url is matched to `http//stackoverflow.com`

Sample output like

```
http:/stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Comment: Beyond the horrible formatting issues, this is not a very good question for SO. We are here to help you with code that you've tried but doesn't work, not to write procedures for you. Have you tried anything? If so, it would be advisable to post that before asking for help from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter_var() function for this purpose in  php.

```
    $s="Does anyone have a working preg_match script for checking and validating a correct url submission into a html form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/ validating http://google.com";

$words = explode(' ',$s );
$urls = array();
foreach($words as $word){

if(!(filter_var($word, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED) === FALSE))
        {
         /*** try to the filter the URL ***/
        $urls[] = $word;
        }


}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($urls);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```